# Electret Mic Circuit Using JFET Bootstrap

Tags: audio, jfet, electret, bootstrap

I thought this circuit was clever so I'm sharing:

[image: electret microphone circuit with fet bootstrap]

The JFET current source is bootstrapping the electret and thereby providing 20dB of linearized gain. The bootstapping network also provides for some frequency shaping and the output is buffered.

So this isn't really a question but criticism is welcome. How would *you* improve this circuit?

Comment: This electret has a built-in JFET, right?

Answer (score 1):

- Positive feedback from the output increases output impedance and load sensitivity. Add a voltage buffer to the output to more predictably drive a wide variety of loads or cable lengths.
- See [this awesome appnote](http://www.colorado.edu/physics/phys3330/phys3330_fa05/pdfdocs/AN102FETbiasing.pdf) for more than you ever wanted to know about JFET biasing.
- See also the [SRPP/mu-amp/whatever](http://www.tubecad.com/2009/10/blog0173.htm) circuit for further inspiration.